# spark filter column from dataframe with words from a collection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

i have been searching for a while but i haven't found how to do it.
i have a dataframe that contains a reference to a table and one of the columns contains a string

```
dataframe schema: name string,lastname string, interests string
```

i have a list of interests like so:

```
val sports:List [String] = List("football","basketball","soccer")
```

i want to filter all the people from my dataframe that contain one of the sports above in their interests

```
val peopledata = sqlContext.sql("select * from learning.people")
```

i have tried to do this like this :

```
for (sport <- sports)peopledata.filter(peopledata("interests").contains(sport))
```

but i have asked a pro in the company i work in, and he told me there he a better and prettier way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Execute `collect()` function to get `Array[Row]` of results and filter elements of this array with `sports.contains()`:

`peopledata.collect().filter(row => sports contains row.getString(2))`

2 here is number of `interests` field in your schema.

Comment: it says it requires an int and it returned a string

Comment: @SparkHelpPlease oops, fixed my answer

Comment: I posted an answer then realised it had a bug so deleted it, but need to mention that by doing a `collect` you will be moving all peopleData to your driver, which might be ok as long as it fits in memory of your driver. An alternative solution is to `broadcast` `sports` and do the filter on the `peopleData` `DataFrame`. I'm afraid I'm out of time but will check back later and post a solution if the question is still open :)

Answer (score 1):

Usage of string interpolation will solve your problem:

```
val interest  = sports.mkString("('","','","')")

val peopledata = sqlContext.sql(s"select * from learning.people where interest in $interest")
```

Comment: i think that wont be enough , because the intrests can be like this:"football,baseball" and so on in one string